# jailbroken apps: chmod on /System/Library/Audio/UISounds not permitted

Tags: ios, jailbreak, chmod

I would like to developp my own tweak. It will use a shell script to replace some UI sounds.
There is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

chmod 755 /System/Library/Audio/UISounds

cd /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/tmp_*myapp*

cp Bubble.caf /System/Library/Audio/UISounds

cd /System/Library/Audio/UISounds

mv Tock.caf sauvegarde_Tock.caf
mv Bubble.caf Tock.caf

exit 0
```

When I try to run the script in Mobile Terminal, I got:
chmod: changing permissions of '/System/Library/Audio/UISounds': Operation not permitted

I've understood that I have to be the root user for run this command line but how I can to do ? I mean how can I write my script for "chmod" works on all iDevices that have downloaded my tweak ?!

I hope you will understood my goal, English is not my primary language ^^'
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: If you are running on mobile terminal then you have to use standard unix commands to gain priveleges (su or sudo)

Comment: Yes, I know that but the issue is that this script is for a tweak, it will be launched when a user will toggle "on" an action, so it will we not be used in MobileTerminal but in Tweak's preferences (You understand me ?)

Comment: toggle on from what?  Obj-C code?

Comment: From the preferences of my Obj-c code

Comment: If you are running Obj-C code you can switch to root user using setuid and setgid

Comment: without asking root password ?

Comment: That's what I've heard.  Anyway everyone knows the iOS root password anyway so even if you needed it, it wouldn't be a big deal ;).

Comment: What do you mean by *"from the preferences of my Obj-C code"*?  Are you talking about an app, a mobilesubstrate tweak that runs in SpringBoard, a `PSListController` or similar that runs in Preferences.app?  Please be specific.

Comment: @@borrrden: oh, it's interessting ! I will looking for. Yes, I know this password but if the people who want download my tweak have change their root password (like me) it can be an issue ^^. For this, I have to find a solution for to do a chmod on /System, but your trick can save me, thanks ^^
                                                               @Nate: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I mean a sort of PSListController that will run in preference.app. In this, the user can toggle on an option and so remplace a UISound by an other by running the script that I've wrotten in the first message !

Comment: Why don't you do this inside your tweak and not shell script? Preferences app has root priveleges so you are OK.